# Can you use case to specify a join to use in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a usermessages table in which all messages sent between two users on a site are stored.

Each message has a `sourceUserId` and a `friendId`, these are the sender and receiver.

Every user message inbox lists all sent and received messages and each message shows which user has sent or received that message.

**The problem**

As we are listing sending and receiving users, some columns are the wrong way around, for example if the userId of the current user is 1

- sent messages will have a sourceUserId of 1
- received messages will have a friendId of 1

If I try and do the whole inbox with one query then I have to currently do two joins on both `sourceUserId` and `friendId` as I can't tell which is the currently logged in user.

I already know the username of the currently logged in user so it does not seem right to have two joins when only one is needed?

I am wondering if it is possible to use some sort of case in a mysql query to effectively achieve the following and reduce the amount of data that has to be looked up each time ..

```
SELECT um.message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(um.time), um.read, user.username
FROM usermessages um
    CASE 
        WHEN um.friendId = 1
            INNER JOIN user ON um.sourceUserId = user.id
        WHEN um.sourceUserId = 1        
            INNER JOIN user ON um.friendId = user.id
    END
WHERE (um.friendId = 1 OR um.sourceUserId = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CASE` for `ON` clause instead

```
SELECT um.message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(um.time), um.read, user.username
FROM usermessages um
INNER JOIN user ON 
    CASE 
        WHEN um.friendId = 1 THEN um.sourceUserId
                             ELSE um.friendId
    END = user.id
WHERE (um.friendId = 1 OR um.sourceUserId = 1)
```

(or move the comparison `= user.id` inside `CASE` if you like it better)

Comment: Thanks, You guys have so much useful query optimization knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, instead of using case when, do it the boolean way:

```
SELECT um.message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(um.time), um.read, user.username
FROM usermessages um
INNER JOIN user ON 
    (um.friendId = 1 AND um.sourceUserId = user.id)
    OR
    um.friendId = user.id
WHERE (um.friendId = 1 OR um.sourceUserId = 1)
```

Comment: Which one would be better to go with? Are there any downsides to case when?

Comment: @Silver89: nope. Both solutions are slow and can't be optimized :-)

Comment: I always write query in this way; besides, non-database programming languages don't exactly have CASE WHENs, everything operate in boolean.  Haven't profile if this is faster than the case when.

Comment: @Michael Buen: "non-database programming languages don't exactly have" -- so what?

Comment: @zerkms Translating this query to Linq (or perhaps HQL(though I don't know if HQL supported CASE WHEN or not)) will be purely mechanical proposition. Has one-to-one correspondence with front-end languages

Comment: @Michael Buen: simplicity of translating pure sql to DBAL is not an argument in this case. (Though I agree with you that it could change the final solution).

Comment: Though to give the benefit of the doubt, if the CASE WHEN involves bi-values only, you can do CASE WHEN on front-end languages using ternary operator: `(um.friendId == 1 ? um.sourceUserId : um.friendId) == user.id`. The code would be entirely different if ternary condition involves multiple condition(would be deeply nested) though

Comment: @zerkms If the `INNER JOIN` tables have foreign keys is it still a poor and slow query to be running?

Comment: @Silver89: `OR` is almost never get optimized